# Parsing Json using JsonReader Class Android

Tags: android, json

I'm a new Android developer having trouble parsing a JSON InputStream using the JsonReader class. Whenever it gets to the reader.beginArray() to begin parsing through the InputStream, it crashes. I used the code at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html as my example. Can someone help me figure this out? By the way, I'm using the JsonReader class because I'm consuming a large amounts of text in other calls.

I'm passing the following URL: --- removed ---

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    static JsonReader reader = null;
    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }



    public List getJSONFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {

        // Making HTTP request

            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            try {
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent(); 



        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }







            try {
                reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
            try {
            reader.beginArray();
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
              messages.add(readMessage(reader));
            }
            reader.endArray();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                return messages;




        // try parse the string to a JSON object


        // return JSON String
        //return reader;

    }



    public Message readMessage(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        long _id = -1;
        String topic_title = null;
        Integer sort_order = null;

        reader.beginObject();
         while (reader.hasNext()) {
           String name = reader.nextName();
           if (name.equals("id")) {
               _id = reader.nextLong();
           } else if (name.equals("topic_title")) {
               topic_title = reader.nextString();

           }           
           else if (name.equals("sort_order")) {
               sort_order = reader.nextInt();

           }
           else {
               reader.skipValue();
           }
         }
         reader.endObject();
         DataBaseHelper.getInstance().updateTopicOrder(_id, sort_order, topic_title);
        return new Message();
      }


}
```

Here is my logcat:

```
12-05 10:08:54.806: D/gralloc_goldfish(582): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-05 10:08:56.367: D/dalvikvm(582): GC_CONCURRENT freed 146K, 3% free 10139K/10375K, paused 19ms+10ms
12-05 10:12:17.466: W/webcore(582): java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.
12-05 10:12:17.466: W/webcore(582):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:1671)
12-05 10:12:17.466: W/webcore(582):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.access$7800(WebViewCore.java:920)
12-05 10:12:17.466: W/webcore(582):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:1783)
12-05 10:12:17.466: W/webcore(582):     at android.webkit.WebView.sendOurVisibleRect(WebView.java:2858)
12-05 10:12:17.466: W/webcore(582):     at android.webkit.ZoomManager.setZoomScale(ZoomManager.java:586)
12-05 10:12:17.466: W/webcore(582):     at android.webkit.ZoomManager.access$1700(ZoomManager.java:49)
12-05 10:12:17.466: W/webcore(582):     at android.webkit.ZoomManager$PostScale.run(ZoomManager.java:977)
12-05 10:12:17.466: W/webcore(582):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-05 10:12:17.466: W/webcore(582):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-05 10:12:17.466: W/webcore(582):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-05 10:12:17.466: W/webcore(582):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-05 10:12:17.466: W/webcore(582):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 10:12:17.466: W/webcore(582):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-05 10:12:17.466: W/webcore(582):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-05 10:12:17.466: W/webcore(582):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-05 10:12:17.466: W/webcore(582):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-05 10:12:19.146: D/dalvikvm(582): GC_CONCURRENT freed 179K, 4% free 10370K/10695K, paused 5ms+8ms
12-05 10:12:19.616: W/dalvikvm(582): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
12-05 10:12:19.672: E/AndroidRuntime(582): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
12-05 10:12:19.672: E/AndroidRuntime(582): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-05 10:12:19.672: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
12-05 10:12:19.672: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-05 10:12:19.672: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-05 10:12:19.672: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-05 10:12:19.672: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-05 10:12:19.672: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
12-05 10:12:19.672: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-05 10:12:19.672: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-05 10:12:19.672: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-05 10:12:19.672: E/AndroidRuntime(582): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT
12-05 10:12:19.672: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at android.util.JsonReader.expect(JsonReader.java:310)
12-05 10:12:19.672: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at android.util.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:277)
12-05 10:12:19.672: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at com.gotquestions.gqandapp.util.JSONParser.readMessagesArray(JSONParser.java:82)
12-05 10:12:19.672: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at com.gotquestions.gqandapp.util.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:73)
12-05 10:12:19.672: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at com.gotquestions.gqandapp.ac.UpdaterActivity$updateTopics.doInBackground(UpdaterActivity.java:108)
12-05 10:12:19.672: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at com.gotquestions.gqandapp.ac.UpdaterActivity$updateTopics.doInBackground(UpdaterActivity.java:1)
12-05 10:12:19.672: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
12-05 10:12:19.672: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-05 10:12:19.672: E/AndroidRuntime(582):  ... 5 more
12-05 10:12:24.938: I/Process(582): Sending signal. PID: 582 SIG: 9
12-05 10:14:39.988: W/ActivityThread(645): Application com.gotquestions.gqandapp is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
12-05 10:14:40.097: I/System.out(645): Sending WAIT chunk
12-05 10:14:40.137: I/dalvikvm(645): Debugger is active
12-05 10:14:40.216: I/System.out(645): Debugger has connected
12-05 10:14:40.216: I/System.out(645): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:14:40.416: I/System.out(645): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:14:40.617: I/System.out(645): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:14:40.817: I/System.out(645): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:14:41.027: I/System.out(645): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:14:41.228: I/System.out(645): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:14:41.427: I/System.out(645): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:14:41.627: I/System.out(645): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:14:41.827: I/System.out(645): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:14:42.052: I/System.out(645): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:14:42.247: I/System.out(645): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:14:42.462: I/System.out(645): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:14:42.674: I/System.out(645): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:14:42.881: I/System.out(645): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:14:43.086: I/System.out(645): debugger has settled (1352)
12-05 10:14:46.566: D/gralloc_goldfish(645): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-05 10:14:47.616: D/dalvikvm(645): GC_CONCURRENT freed 149K, 3% free 10138K/10375K, paused 6ms+6ms
12-05 10:19:45.851: D/dalvikvm(645): Debugger has detached; object registry had 594 entries
12-05 10:21:11.577: W/ActivityThread(707): Application com.gotquestions.gqandapp is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
12-05 10:21:11.668: I/System.out(707): Sending WAIT chunk
12-05 10:21:11.677: I/dalvikvm(707): Debugger is active
12-05 10:21:11.747: I/System.out(707): Debugger has connected
12-05 10:21:11.747: I/System.out(707): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:21:11.987: I/System.out(707): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:21:12.197: I/System.out(707): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:21:12.397: I/System.out(707): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:21:12.597: I/System.out(707): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:21:12.799: I/System.out(707): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:21:13.007: I/System.out(707): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:21:13.207: I/System.out(707): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:21:13.407: I/System.out(707): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:21:13.607: I/System.out(707): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:21:13.820: I/System.out(707): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:21:14.017: I/System.out(707): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:21:14.227: I/System.out(707): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:21:14.427: I/System.out(707): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:21:14.626: I/System.out(707): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:21:14.864: I/System.out(707): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 10:21:15.078: I/System.out(707): debugger has settled (1364)
12-05 10:21:18.457: D/gralloc_goldfish(707): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-05 10:21:19.567: D/dalvikvm(707): GC_CONCURRENT freed 151K, 3% free 10136K/10375K, paused 7ms+7ms
12-05 10:21:28.467: D/dalvikvm(707): GC_CONCURRENT freed 160K, 3% free 10401K/10695K, paused 6ms+8ms
```

Comment: which android os you are using? When app crash do not forget to post `Logcat`

Comment: I am using Android 4.0. I'll attach the logcat...thanks

Comment: yet another [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Comment: but I'm calling this from a class that extends AsyncTask

Comment: hmm, then I guess the problem is in `reader.beginArray();` It seam you are reading `JsonObject` as a `JsonArray`

Comment: yes - that is where it is hanging up, at the reader.beginArray(). I'm doing that because at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html it says that to begin reading the first token, I have to do a beginArray()

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20645/discussion-between-m-mohsin-naeem-and-rob-bushway)

Comment: ...Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT ... it means your json start from object not array ... its object with property called ropics and this property is array ... so first you should consume this start object and name

Comment: thank you Sevin and M Moshin Naeem !

Answer (score 0):

Your log say

12-05 10:12:19.672: E/AndroidRuntime(582): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

In Json format this "{}" is Object and "[]" is array

See your json file i think it start with an object. If start with object change your line of code to start by reading an object and not an array.

```
try {
        reader.beginObject();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
          messages.add(readMessage(reader));
        }
        reader.endObject();
        }
```

Note: Close the stream after use. The common way is to put the code into finally block.